# How to pass full data set to a Form from another class?

Tags: c#

I want to keep reading data process separate in a class and pass that data to the a Form to display in the DataGridView as data source. I can build row by row in a List and then pass that to the Form but I am wondering if there is simple way of just passing complete data set to the form as parameter?

Here is my code to build the dataset:

```
class DAL_ProjectMaster
{
    // List<string> ProjectList = new List<string>();
    OleDbConnection DBcon;
    OleDbCommand DBcmd;
    OleDbDataAdapter DBadp;
    ConString constr = new ConString();
    public void GetProjectMaster()
    {
        string connectString = constr.GetConString();

        DBcon = new OleDbConnection(connectString);
        DBcmd = new OleDbCommand("select * from ProjectMaster", DBcon);
        DBcon.Open();
        DBadp = new OleDbDataAdapter(DBcmd);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        DBadp.Fill(ds);
       }
    }
}
```

I would like to pass ds to the Form where I can use as data source for DataGridview like this:

```
      dataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change `GetProjectMaster` to return `DataSet`

```
public DataSet GetProjectMaster()
{
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    string connectString = constr.GetConString();
    using( var con = new OleDbConnection(connectString))
    using( var cmd = new OleDbCommand("select * from ProjectMaster", con))
    {
        con.Open();
        using(var adp = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmd))
        {
            adp.Fill(ds);
        }
    }
    return ds;
}
```

now you can call above method as

```
DAL_ProjectMaster dal = new DAL_ProjectMaster();
dataGridView1.DataSource = dal.GetProjectMaster().Tables[0];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use session
//for assign

```
  DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    Session.Add("Name", ds);
    // for retrieve
    ds = (DataSet)Session["Name"];
```